# Create conda environment with platform-specific python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, conda, apple-m1

I sifted through many similar questions but couldn't find an answer to my question. I am trying to create a conda environment not only with a specific Python version, but a specific platform too. The following command (and variations thereof) fails:

```
conda create -n test python=3.9.11-macos11
```

I am not sure how conda sources different Python versions, but the version above is [available](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.11/) on Python.org, and I want that specific version. Alternatively it would be useful to know if environments can be created with *local* Python archives (e.g. `.pkg` or `.tgz` files on-disk but not "installed" on the system); I tried using `python=file://path/to/python-3.9.11-macos11.pkg` and the FTP URL directly but to no avail.

### More context

I am on an M1 Mac and installed conda with `Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh`. The built-in Python version indicates the correct architecture:

```
$ python3 -c "import os; print(os.uname().machine)"                                           
arm64
```

However Python versions installed via `conda` do not:

```
$ conda create -n test python=3.9
$ conda activate test
$ python3 -c "import os; print(os.uname().machine)" 
x86_64
```

FYI this is unrelated to setting `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0` (but to be sure I tried it and it doesn't help). Installing and using the Python version linked above does yield the expected result, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the default channels for conda were not set correctly during the installation of Miniconda. Creating a file `~/.condarc` as below yields the expected behavior simply using `python=3.9`.

Note that the first channel is `osx-arm64` and not `osx-64`, which corresponds to the channels listed [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/):

```
channels:
 - main/osx-arm64
 - main/noarch
 - free/osx-64
 - free/noarch
 - r/osx-64
 - r/noarch
```